# I did error check on DataGrip but the sql file was still generating a syntax error when I try to run it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax-error, datagrip

So I was installing a schema on my MySql database. I error checked the sql script on DataGrip, it shows no syntax error; yet when I runt it the syntax error pop up

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 54: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the    right syntax to use near '.ortholog_seq_a_ix on orthomcl.ortholog(sequence_id_a)' at line 1

The original code is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE orthomcl.Ortholog (
SEQUENCE_ID_A           VARCHAR(15),
SEQUENCE_ID_B           VARCHAR(15),
TAXON_ID_A              VARCHAR(15),
TAXON_ID_B              VARCHAR(15),
UNNORMALIZED_SCORE      DOUBLE,
NORMALIZED_SCORE        DOUBLE    
);

CREATE INDEX orthomcl.ortholog_seq_a_ix on orthomcl.ortholog(sequence_id_a);
```

By the way I'm using an ubuntu system.

Comment: I created an issue in JetBrains issue tracker, please watch this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX ortholog_seq_a_ix on orthomcl.ortholog(sequence_id_a);
```

Does it work? May be you don't need to specify schema in index definition if it's already specified in table def